# Difference of direct coded scanners and hand coded scanners

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

As I understood it the difference between a table driven scanner and a direct coded scanner is that the tds uses a transition table while in the dcs this transition is modelled as program code instead of a table.

But what is then the difference between a direct coded scanner and a hand coded scanner?

Comment: In this context I believe they are the same.

Comment: And what would be the difference in general or in another context?

Comment: I would need to know that other context :)

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the direct coded and the hand coded scanners is that the direct coded scanners are automatically generated but the hand coded scanners are written manually by the developer.

In direct coded scanners, the logic for recognizing the tokens is directly written in the programming language without relying on external data structures or tables.

In hand coded scanners, the developer tries to take the best of both worlds (table driven and direct coded). The best choices for implementation of the scanner depends on the programming language. Since the developer knows about the language, he/she can make the most optimal choices which is why the hand coded scanners usually provide better performance than the table driven and direct coded ones.

For more in depth details, you can refer these slides: https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/swarnendu/courses/spring2023-cs335/lexical-analysis.pdf